# Tutis login: Foreach not works

Tags: php, authentication, foreach, pdo

I started using the [Tutis login](http://www.firedartstudios.com/labs/tutis-login) script. I made some changes but the following is giving me errors:

I want to list all the registered users but the Foreach Loop isn't working.

I created a new function in the member.class.php:

```
// Registered Users
public function rusers() 
{
    global $database;

    $notice = new notice;
    $users = $database->query('SELECT id, username, date FROM users');

    $return_form = 1;

    $user = "<table>"
          . "<tr>"
          . "<td>ID</td>"
          . "<td>UserName</td>"
          . "<td>Date</td>"
          . "</tr>";

    // Function in the database.class.php
    $result = $database->foreachloop($users); 

    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $user.= "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
        $user.= "<td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['date']."</td></tr>";
    }
    $user.= "</table>"; 

    /* Combine Data */
    $data = "";

    /* Do we need the login form? */
    if ($return_form == 1) 
    {
        $data .= $user;
    }

    /* Return data */
    return $notice->report() . $data;
}
```

And added the foreachloop() function in the database.class.php

```
public function foreachloop($result)
{
    return $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

But I get the following long error:

```
*Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\wamp\www\loginoop3\assets\member.class.php on line 996
Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in C:\wamp\www\loginoop3\assets\member.class.php on line 997
Warning: Illegal string offset 'date' in C:\wamp\www\loginoop3\assets\member.class.php on line 997
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\wamp\www\loginoop3\assets\member.class.php on line 996
Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in C:\wamp\www\loginoop3\assets\member.class.php on line 997
Warning: Illegal string offset 'date' in C:\wamp\www\loginoop3\assets\member.class.php on line 997*
```

And the output is:

```
*ID UserName Date
t   t        t
2   2        2*
```

Here the 2 number means the user ID and the "t" letter is the "test" username but only show the first letter... And only shows one user but there are more users.

I don't know whats wrong. Are there someone any suggestion?

This login uses OOP PDO. And I tried to do this changes by the rowCount() as it had a new function in the database.class.php with the following content:

```
public function affected($result)
{
    return $this->statement->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: dump out result and see what you get back. this is saying that those indices don't exist within the array.

Comment: var_dump($result); OUTPUT: array (size=3)
  'id' => int 2
  'username' => string 'test' (length=5)
  'date' => string '2012-10-10' (length=10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to user961627 (original function from the creator of tutis login):

Function in member.class.php:

```
/**
 * list_users
 *
 * Returns a list of users that are registerd
 */
public function list_users() {
    global $database;

    $users = $database->query('SELECT id, username, date FROM users', null, "fetchAll");

    $data = "<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Registered</td>
</tr>";

    foreach ($users as $row) {
        $data.= "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
        $data.= "<td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['date']."</td></tr>";
    }

    $data.= "</table>"; 

    /* Return data */
    return $data;
}
```

Call it by using:

```
echo $member->list_users();
```

Answer (score 1):

So result is not an array of arrays, it's just one level deep. Which is why this isn't working:

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $user.= "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    $user.= "<td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['date']."</td></tr>";
}
```

`$result['username']` would work just fine. You don't need the `foreach`. Does that make sense?

Comment: But $result['username'] prints out only one username but I want to print out ALL registered users username, so I need a kind of loop

Comment: if I change to this: public function foreachloop($result){
  return array($this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
 } (add array() ) than I get only one row too but it print out OK the username "test"

Comment: Why is it only one level deep? How to fech the all data?

Comment: Hey @Gery, did you manage a solution? I have a similar question - would you mind sharing if you solved this?